# What is the "three-asterisk-break" section called?

Tags: novel, formatting

What is the name for a text subdivision that is shorter than a chapter, but longer than a paragraph? They are always untitled (unlike chapters, which are at the very least called "Chapter 1", "2" etc), and denoted with either three asterisks, a longer blank space between paragraphs, or some other fancy marks.

(specifically, I'm not asking about name for the break itself, but for the section of text delimited by such breaks.)

Comment: I think that would be a scene. In most works I read it came when the place or characters changed, thus signaling a change in scene and in time.

Comment: @Mussri: Submit that as an answer.

Comment: I found [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40379/is-there-a-proper-name-for-the-3-asterisks-that-are-used-to-suggest-temporal-dis) on English.SE. I'm not sure if this makes it a duplicate or...

Comment: @Mussri: Not really (though the answer includes an answer to my question). See the parenthesized sentence at the end of my question.

Comment: @Mussri - That question does answer this, but I think this question covers a little more ground than that. In any case, I don't think duplicates on different sites are necessarily a problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A question was [asked](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40379/is-there-a-proper-name-for-the-3-asterisks-that-are-used-to-suggest-temporal-dis) on English.SE about what the marks themselves are called.

The only answer there states that most marks that separate logical chunks of text, signaling a change in focus/time/characters (or whatever the main point of the writing is) are called 'section/scene separators'.

So I logically assume that bits of text they separate would be 'sections' or, more appropriately in fiction writing, 'scenes.'

As for my real-world experience, I've seen such marks (including a double paragraph break in more recent fiction publications) used to signal change in scenes (and therefore, time) with the connotation of 'this isn't as big a change as between chapters.'

Comment: There is a fundamental difference between the internal and visual structure of a text. A scene break may or may not happen at a chapter, section or paragraph break. In fact it may happen *within a sentence!* E.g.: "At the beach, the children laughed with their father, while at home their mother prepared dinner." Here the scene break happens at ", while". It is therefore important to not confuse terms from different structural levels.

Answer (score 4):

The subdivisions of a chapter, signified by an asterism (⁂), dinkus (* * *), or extra space, are called **[sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_%28typography%29)**.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you would call this a **section**. For fiction, a **scene** (or maybe a **sequence** if the portion of text covers multiple scenes),

Comment: All of these are names for the group of paragraphs before the symbol in question.

Answer (score 0):

In typesetting, this is sometimes called a 'dinkus' -- see here: http://www.thenewsmanual.net/Resources/glossary.html#D

Answer (score -2):

It's also a sort of ellipsis signifying a break in narrative time.

Comment: Hiya! I'm afraid this doesn't answer the question - the original poster asked what the section is *called*; what you're doing is describing its *purpose*, which is already understood.